# Не присваивается класс по событию

Tags: jquery

Добрый день. Суть такова, что в случае, если в инпуте количество символов превышает единицу, то к инпуту присваивается класс .valid. Но скрипт почему-то не работает. Я ввожу символы в инпут, а класс не присваивается.

```
    $(function() {
        input = $('#contact-form input');
         if(input.text().length >= 1) {
            input.addClass('valid');
        }
        else {
            input.removeClass('valid');
        }
    });
```

Comment: `if (input.val().length >= 1) {`

Comment: @Igor может ты не заметил, но тут нигде не подписываются на событие :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы не подписались на событие изменения поля. А значит ваш код сработает лишь 1 раз при инициализации.

На чистом JS:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
input.addEventListener('input', function () {
  if(this.value.length >= 1) {
    this.classList.add('valid');
  }
  else {
    this.classList.remove('valid');
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid red;
  outline: none;
}
.valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
```

С использование jQuery (только js код):

```
$(function() {
  var input = $('#input');
  input.on('input', function () {
    // тут можно использовать this, как элемент DOM модели, а не jQuery объект, и использовать не input, а this, НО будет как в примере на чистом js
    if(input.val().length >= 1) {
      input.addClass('valid');
    }
    else {
      input.removeClass('valid');
    }
  });
});
```